# Working glib library not found while trying to run configure file

Tags: c++, linux, config

I need to run configure file but I get the following error:
[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGD1b.png)

I've installed the following dependencies:
libssl-dev
GLib 2.32
libglib2.0-dev

still didn't help.

Comment: checking for g_hash_table_new in -lglib : "Checks if key is in hash_table . Available since: 2.32." ........ $ readelf -s [path to]libglib-2* | grep -i hash ............. You should avoid posting pictures of text https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: I'm new here, and it didn't let me paste the picture, only like that

Comment: exist in it's newest version